# AS3 DropShadowFilter() with a 3D instance

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have an instance on stage that has a `DropShadowFilter()` added by code, when I change `rotationX`or `rotationY` of that instance, the angle of `DropShadowFilter()` goes crazy, so my question

How can I make the angle of the `DropShadowFilter()` fixed while altering the 3D properties of an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sprite wrapper should do. You wrap your instance in a Sprite, add a `new DropShadowFilter()` to the instance, and change `rotationX` or `rotationY` on the wrapper sprite. This way the filter will continue to operate in a 2D space and will retain correctness, while the complete object will be rotated in 3D via wrapper.